# Installing Git HTML Help on OSX

Tags: macos, git

I've tried to install the Git HTML help pages on OSX according to the instructions provided by the following links:

- http://help.github.com/install-git-html-help/
- http://www.railsatwork.com/2010/12/installing-git-html-documentation-on.html

But when I get to the final verification step that involves running:

```
git help --web commit
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: '/usr/local/git/share/doc/git-doc': not a documentation directory
```

I've verified that the folder, /usr/local/git/share/doc/git-doc was in fact created when I ran "git clone", and that it is full of files that appear to be git documentation files.

Can someone let me know what I am missing?  Thanks!

Here is a short list of some of the files that were created in the git-doc folder:

- exec_cmd.c
- exec_cmd.h
- fast-import.c
- fetch-pack.h
- fixup-builtins
- fmt-merge-msg.h
- fsck.c
- fsck.h
- generate-cmdlist.sh
- gettext.c
- gettext.h
- git-add--interactive.perl
- git-am.sh
- git-archimport.perl
- git-bisect.sh
- git-compat-util.h
- git-cvsexportcommit.perl
- git-cvsimport.perl
- git-cvsserver.perl
- git-difftool--helper.sh
- git-difftool.perl
- git-filter-branch.sh

EDIT:
Just looked over the git clone results and found this warning, not sure if it makes a difference:
"Remote branch html not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead"

Comment: You do have a `.git` directory in your `/usr/local/git/share/doc/git-doc`?

Comment: yep.  I was also able to run 'sudo git pull' just fine from within said directory

Comment: but there's no html branch there: $ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/maint
  origin/master
  origin/next
  origin/pu
  origin/todo

Comment: yeah...see my edit.  Would that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change clone command address from

```
$ sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git git-doc --branch html
```

to

```
$ sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-htmldocs.git git-doc
```

Hope this will be changed in Github tutorial soon.

UPDATE:

If you are one of those who thinks it’s enough to have Apple Git distribution supplied with Xcode 4:

```
# create directory to keep Git documentation html-files
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/git/share/doc # or whatever directory you choose

# change to that directory
$ cd /usr/local/git/share/doc

# clone repo with documentation 
$ sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-htmldocs.git git-doc 

# point your Git explicitly to a new documentation directory
$ git config --global help.htmlpath /usr/local/git/share/doc/git-doc

# tell Git to use html-formatted help by default
$ git config --global help.format html
```

This will create an entry in your .gitconfig like:

```
[help]
    format = html
    htmlpath = /usr/local/git/share/doc/git-doc
```

Comment: Using Homebrew, my help docs were located at `/usr/local/Cellar/git/$GIT_VERSION/share/doc/git-doc`, e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.22.0_1/share/doc/git-doc`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ([`builtin/help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/help.c#L381)):

```
static void get_html_page_path(struct strbuf *page_path, const char *page)
{
  struct stat st;
  const char *html_path = system_path(GIT_HTML_PATH);

  /* Check that we have a git documentation directory. */
  if (stat(mkpath("%s/git.html", html_path), &st)
      || !S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
    die("'%s': not a documentation directory.", html_path);

  strbuf_init(page_path, 0);
  strbuf_addf(page_path, "%s/%s.html", html_path, page);
}
```

So there might be some issue with `GIT_HTML_PATH` environment variable (as in that [old issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/16749)), or you don't have any `git.html` file in your destination help directory.

Comment: Which is my destination help directory?  Would it be as simple as just looking for a file named git.html in that that directory?

Comment: @uglymunky: it seems it should be as simple as a that: try at least a '`find . -name "git.html" -print`' in the `git-doc` directory.