# Git Bash Terminal replies fatal : "C:/....": not a documentation directory

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I entered this command on Git Bash Terminal on Windows and I got this:

```
   Anurag Nihal@LAPTOP-DK8BSQJ5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/first-project (master)
   $ find .git/objects -type f
   .git/objects/44/00aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08
   .git/objects/b7/aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e
   (base)
   Anurag Nihal@LAPTOP-DK8BSQJ5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/first-project (master)
   $ help git mktree
   bash: help: no help topics match `mktree'.  Try `help help' or `man -k 
   mktree' or `info mktree'.
   (base)
   Anurag Nihal@LAPTOP-DK8BSQJ5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/first-project (master)
   $ git mktree --help
   fatal: 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/mingw64/share/doc/git-doc': not a 
   documentation directory.
   (base)
   Anurag Nihal@LAPTOP-DK8BSQJ5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/first-project (master)
   $ echo $HOME
   /c/Users/Anurag Nihal
   (base)
```

Kindly help me what should I do? I searched here and on the internet but most of them are for the working directory or the home directory. If I can get to know how to change the documentation directory, it will be very much helpful. I have recently started programming.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @tripleee Ok. will take of it from now on.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically trying to tell you that the documentation isn't installed where it thought it would be.

You can find it online easily; https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktree

If you have the HTML documentation files installed locally in `C:\whatever`, try

```sh
git config --global help.htmlPath C:\whatever
```

Comment: Can I know how to change my documentation directory to the original one? I searched here and on the internet but most of them are for the working directory or the home directory.

Comment: By quick glance the `help.htmlPath` configuration option should point to a directory where the documentation is installed ... I think. I (fortunately) don't have Windows and you are not revealing how you installed Git so we can't really tell you if these files are installed on your system, and if so, where.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709383/installing-git-html-help-on-osx but it seems rather old. The friendly link to Github in the question no longer works, for example.

Comment: There is no "normally"; explain what you did. Followed which instructions, downloaded from where? The Anaconda in your path suggests you might have used Anaconda, is that not correct? The command to set this configuration option is `git config help.htmlPath C:\whatever`

Comment: No, I followed the course setup of  Bogdan in Udemy. And I didn't use Anaconda for it. It also surprised me how it is there.https://www.udemy.com/course/git-and-github-complete-guide/

Comment: git config help.htmlPath "C:\Program 
               Files\Git\mingw64\share\doc\git-doc"    Helped. Thank you @Tripleee

Answer (score 0):

This will be better handled with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), where the error in "[`git help no-such-git-command`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd42622e5f3ea4a5b1f5fd69174bc7914d00ea3e/Documentation/git-help.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help))</sup>  is handled better.

See [commit a3952f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3952f8e7c0e74d9266bc9cf4ac50dd179129f72) (14 Sep 2021) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd42622](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd42622e5f3ea4a5b1f5fd69174bc7914d00ea3e), 23 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`help`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3952f8e7c0e74d9266bc9cf4ac50dd179129f72): make sure local html page exists before calling external processes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthias Aßhauer</sup>

> We check that `git.html` exists, regardless of the page the user wants to open.
> Checking whether the requested page exists instead gives us a smoother user experience in two use cases:
>
> 1. The requested page doesn't exist
>
> When calling a git command and there is an error, most users reasonably expect git to produce an error message on the standard error stream, but in this case we pass the filepath to [`git web--browse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a3952f8e7c0e74d9266bc9cf4ac50dd179129f72/Documentation/git-web--browse.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-web--browse))</sup> which passes it on to a browser (or a helper program like xdg-open or start that should in turn open a browser) without any error and many GUI based browsers or helpers won't output such a message onto the standard error stream.
>
> Especially the helper programs tend to show the corresponding error message in a message box and wait for user input before exiting.
> This leaves users in interactive console sessions without an error message in their console, without a console prompt and without the help page they expected.
>
> 2. `git.html` is missing for some reason, but the user asked for some other page
>
> We currently refuse to show any local html help page when we can't find `git.html`.
> Even if the requested help page exists.
> If we check for the requested page instead, we can show the user all available pages and only error out on those that don't exist.

So no more:

```
xxx not a documentation directory
```

Rather:

```
'yyy.html': documentation file not found
```